# Unable to find my porlet under sample category in liferay 6.2

Tags: liferay

[image] 
I am new to liferay 6.2![enter image description here][2].I have created a portlet named EmployeeLiferayMVC in my eclipse IDE and build with ant.Build is successful.Now i am running the application in tomcat,and logging as admin.But under sample category i can not find my porlet to add.I have mapping of sample in the liferay-display.xml.

```
<display>
<category name="category.sample">
    <portlet id="EmployeeLiferayMVC" />
    <portlet id="Employee Liferay Mvc"></portlet>
  </category>
</display>
```

I am attaching my screenshot upto what i have done.Somebody please help.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Catalina log

```
 Nov 24, 2014 3:05:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production   environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files   (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.7.0_03/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin;c:\app\Jeet\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;F:\eclipse\eclipse;;.
 Nov 24, 2014 3:05:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
       Nov 24, 2014 3:05:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
      INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
  Nov 24, 2014 3:05:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
 INFO: Initialization processed in 535 ms
 Nov 24, 2014 3:05:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 24, 2014 3:05:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Nov 24, 2014 3:05:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor F:\liferay resource\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-  7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
Nov 24, 2014 3:06:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\liferay resource\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\calendar-portlet
Nov 24, 2014 3:06:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\liferay resource\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\kaleo-web
Nov 24, 2014 3:06:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\liferay resource\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\marketplace-portlet
Nov 24, 2014 3:06:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\liferay resource\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\MyFirstPortlet-portlet
Nov 24, 2014 3:07:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\liferay resource\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\notifications-portlet
Nov 24, 2014 3:07:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\liferay resource\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\opensocial-portlet
Nov 24, 2014 3:07:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory F:\liferay resource\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\resources-importer-web
```

Comment: This may sound silly but after you've built your plugin did you deploy it?

Comment: yes i have deployed it and thats why i am attaching the screenshot

Comment: Make sure that id attribute you provided in liferay-display.xml is the portlet-name tag values of portlet.xml.

Comment: ...and check the logs. Did your portlet actually deploy?

Comment: @OlafKock i think that my portlet is not deploying actually but how to check that what message should come in my console when the portlet is not correctly deployed

Comment: @PankajKathiriya both are correct

Comment: @lucifer it's hard to say what's in there when there's a condition that the portlet is not deployed - it might be the error message that helps you track down the root cause. If I'd be able to tell you what's in there, I might be able to tell you the solution already. Why don't you post the logs that Liferay prints after you put your plugin into Liferay's "deploy" folder?

Comment: @OlafKock i am  wondering about one thing when i am doing Liferay>SDK>deploy the console is showing  success but the message  1 portlet is ready for use is not coming ... i am giving the screenshot

Comment: If you're running tomcat, you'll find the relevant log in `${liferay-home}/tomcat-x.x.x/logs/catalina.out` - the screenshots don't help that much. Also, check if `${liferay-home}/deploy` is where your build process actually places the build results. The `deploy` directory should be empty by default and only contain the deployable files for a few seconds. Please post what gets added to the logfile once you built your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

If the deploy was successful you should have received a message in the tomcat log like:
"1 portlet for {your portlet name} is available for use"

If you are new to liferay you may find this site helpful to get your first portlet working:
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/-/knowledge_base/6-2/writing-your-first-liferay-application

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error resolved by running the portlet on server...
Right click on your portlet-> Run as-> Run on server
your portlet will be deployed.